# Translation of “The word he embodied” to Neutral Spanish

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

What is the best translation for the phrase “The word he embodied” to Neutral Spanish, considering the best to apply? Because, as it's known, if the translation is made literally, sometimes it doesn't turn out fine or it means a different thing.

Comment: Could you please provide the full sentence? Context is required for the translation to be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase you're looking to translate has a bit of a religious ring to it, to my ear.  So I tried googling the phrase, along with the word `Christianity`.  Bingo.  Lots of hits.  Next I put your phrase into linguee.com.  Consistently, through a number of example usage sentences in the religion context, I found

**personificar**

For example:

> The embodied Word of God: La Palabra de Dios personificada

Thus, your phrase, "the word he embodied” would likely be expressed among Spanish-speaking Christians as

> La Palabra que Él personificó

I must emphasize that I'm proceeding logically, *not by ear*, as I have almost zero personal knowledge of Christianity in either language.

Comment: In Christian religion, we say "el Verbo encarnado" to refer to Christ as the embodiment of the word of God. However, "personificar" could work in other contexts.

Comment: @Gustavson please note that the question was about "neutral spanish", in which case this answer makes more sense to me.

Comment: @walen Yes, I have also heard "el Verbo hecho carne", but on the Internet "Verbo encarnado" beats it 594,000 to 80,100. What is much more common is its use as a tensed verb: *El Verbo se hizo carne*, unless you say *El Verbo se encarnó **en** Jesús*.

Comment: Sorry, everyone, I don't have anything in my ear for this.  I just went by what I saw in linguee.  Hopefully someone with a strong connection to this particular religion will be able to give us a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The word he embodied

Se traduciría como

> La palabra que él *encarnó*

To [embody](https://www.wordnik.com/words/embody) —*To give a bodily form to; incarnate*—represents the same than the verb [encarnar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=F1NJCuQ)

> encarnar
>
> 6 dicho de un espíritu o una idea, tomar forma corporal

Comment: Thank you for the answer